# My script doesn't work like an add-on

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am writing a script for the Composition tab and it works when I run it in the Scripts tab, so I want it to be an add-on. I found the manual and added the lines that need to be added, then I installed my addon and enabled it, but it doesn't appear, when I start Blender. So, how can I achieve the desired result?

```
bl_info = {"name" : "CustomeCompositingNodeGroup",  "location": "Compositing", "category": "Node", "author": "Hey there"}
import bpy

class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custome Compositing Node"
    bl_idname = "MainPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Custom nodes"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        column = layout.column()
        column.operator('node.pixelazer_operator')
        column.operator('node.cast_shadow_operator')
        column.operator('node.glitch_effect_operator')
        column.operator('node.outline_operator')

def create_pixelazer_group_node(context, operator, group_name):
    #code
    return pixelazer_group_node

class NODE_OT_PIXELATE(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Pixelazer Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.pixelazer_operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        custom_node_name = 'Pixelazer Node'
        my_group = create_pixelazer_group_node(self, context, custom_node_name)
        pixelazer_node = context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')
        pixelazer_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
        pixelazer_node.use_custom_color = True
        pixelazer_node.color = (0.5,0.1,0.7)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def create_cast_shadow_group_node(context, operator, group_name):
    #code
    return cast_shadow_group_node

class NODE_OT_CAST_SHADOW(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Cast Shadow Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.cast_shadow_operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        custom_node_name = 'Cast Shadow Node'
        my_group = create_cast_shadow_group_node(self, context, custom_node_name)
        cast_shadow_node = context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')
        cast_shadow_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
        cast_shadow_node.use_custom_color = True
        cast_shadow_node.color = (0.2,0.3,0.1)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def create_glitch_effect_group_node(context, operator, group_name):
    #code
    return glitch_effect_group_node

class NODE_OT_GLITCH_EFFECT(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Glitch Effect Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.glitch_effect_operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        custom_node_name = 'Glitch Effect Node'
        my_group = create_glitch_effect_group_node(self, context, custom_node_name)
        glicth_effect_node = context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')
        glicth_effect_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
        glicth_effect_node.use_custom_color = True
        glicth_effect_node.color = (0.1,0.6,0.3)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def create_outline_group_node(context, operator, group_name):
    #code
    return outline_group_node

class NODE_OT_OUTLINE(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Outline Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.outline_operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        custom_node_name = 'Outline Node'
        my_group = create_outline_group_node(self, context, custom_node_name)
        outline_node = context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeGroup')
        outline_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
        outline_node.use_custom_color = True
        outline_node.color = (0.3,0.3,0.3)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_PIXELATE)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_CAST_SHADOW)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_GLITCH_EFFECT)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_OUTLINE)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_PIXELATE)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_CAST_SHADOW)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_GLITCH_EFFECT)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_OUTLINE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Does it say "Upgrade to 2.8x required" next to the addon in the prefs? Add `"blender": (2, 90, 0)` (or whatever version you want) to bl_info.

Comment: Thank you, that works.